# With Behat/Mink, how to match an exact number?

Tags: behat, mink

I'm trying to match an exact number for a page element with Behat/Mink.

My test looks like this:

```
Then the "td.points" element should contain "1"
```

This matches if `td.points` is `1` (good), but it also matches if `td.points` is `10` or `21` (bad).

I tried using a regex like this:

```
Then the "td.views-field-field-int-repetitions" element should contain "\b1\b"
```

But the regex wasn't picked up.

I tried to dig through the code and I see that MinkContext has `assertElementContains`, but I couldn't find anything like `AssertElementIs`.

What I want is something like

```
Then the "td.points" element should be exactly "1"
```

How can I implement this?

EDIT: This is the element contains feature from MinkContext.php:

```
/**
 * Checks, that element with specified CSS contains specified HTML
 * Example: Then the "body" element should contain "style=\"color:black;\""
 * Example: And the "body" element should contain "style=\"color:black;\""
 *
 * @Then /^the "(?P<element>[^"]*)" element should contain "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function assertElementContains($element, $value)
{
    $this->assertSession()->elementContains('css', $element, $this->fixStepArgument($value));
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question and share the exact implementation of the step please?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting the number from the step you could use for a number:

```
the "(.*)" element should contain (\d+)
```

or for string

```
the "(.*)" element should contain "(.*)"
```

or other example for string

```
the "(.*)" element should contain (.*)
```

and for asserting depends on how your code is organized, use what you have or  you could just do:

```
if($someActual != $expected)
{
  throw new \Exception("something meaningful");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lauda, I was able to write the code I wanted:

```
  /**
   * @Then the :element element should be exactly :value
   *
   * Checks that the element with the specified CSS is the exact value.
   */
  public function theElementShouldBeExactly($element, $value) {
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element_text = $page->find('css', "$element")->getText();
    if ($element_text === NULL || strlen($element_text < 1)) {
      throw new Exception("The element $element had a NULL value.");
    }
    if ($element_text !== $value) {
      throw new Exception("Element $element_text did not match value $value.");
    }
  }
```